Integral over a form
In the definition of the integral over a global form of an oriented manifold $M$ we use the fact that it can be obtained by gluing local pieces on which we know how things work. Suppose $\omega$ is a compactly supported top form. Choose a covering of $M$ by sets $\{ U_i \}$ and a partitions of unity $\theta _i $, then the definition, the integral is $\sum \int _M \theta _i \omega$.
Firstly, I don't see the point of using partitions of unity here. Indeed these are normally used to transform local structures into global in a smooth way. In this case $\theta _i$ is supported say in some $U_j$, then it picks out those terms of $\omega$ which are subordinate as top local forms of $U_j$. Couldn't we break $\omega$ into local pieces directly, without using partitions to pick them up part by part?
Secondly, how does this definition of an integral ensure we are not double counting intersections on charts? I was taught to think of integral as something counting area or volume, while it's not intuitive why it is the case by integrating a section to a somewhat 'subterfugely' defined vector bundle.
Lastly, why are we emphasizing that $M$ is orientable? What goes wrong if it isn't and how in particular is it helpful to derive results such as Stoke's Theorem. In my lectures we used induced orientation on $\partial M$ but I don't quite see why do we have to worry about it.
I very much appreciate your help!

It is possible to subdivide a manifold into pieces, where each piece is diffeomorphic to a rectangle and the intersection of the pieces lie in a set of measure zero. The integral over the manifold is then simply the sum of the integrals over the pieces. Doing it this way has a lot of advantages, and I in fact like teaching calculus on manifolds this way. However, the fact that the manifold can be subdivided this way is a hard deep topological theorem. Using a partition of unity is by far an easier way to provide a full rigorous proof.

Welcome, Tanizaki!
Keep in mind that the functions $ \theta _ i $ don't take only the values $ 0 $ and $ 1 $.  The satisfy $ \sum _ i \theta _ i = 1 $ everywhere, even on an overlap $ U _ i \cap U _ j $ where both $ \theta _ i $ and $ \theta _ j $ might be nonzero.  So there's no double-counting, because $ \sum _ i \theta _ i \omega = 1 \omega = \omega $ everywhere.  (In particular, imagine a point $ P $ where $ \theta _ i $ and $ \theta _ j $ are both $ 1 / 2 $; then $ \sum _ i \theta _ i ( P ) \omega ( P ) = \theta _ i ( P ) \omega ( P ) + \theta _ j ( P ) \omega ( P ) = \frac 1 2 \omega ( P ) + \frac 1 2 \omega ( P ) = \omega ( P ) $, not $ \omega ( P ) + \omega ( P ) = 2 \omega ( P ) $.)
One way to think of what the partition of unity does is to express $ \omega $ as a sum $ \omega = \sum _ i \omega _ i $, where only finitely many terms are nonzero at any point and each function $ \omega _ i $ is supported in a single chart $ U _ i $.  (This is done by defining $ \omega _ i = \theta _ i \omega $.)  So in this sense we are breaking $ \omega $ into local pieces, a partition of $ \omega $.  But if you want to prove that it's possible to do this, then rather than directly proving a theorem that any form can be broken up this way, you prove the simpler theorem that the $ 0 $-form $ 1 $ can be broken up this way, and then use the partition of $ 1 $ to define a partition of any form $ \omega $.
Orientability is a separate issue and should probably be asked as a separate question.  You don't need orientability to do the partition; rather, you need it to define the individual integrals $ \int _ { U _ i } \theta _ i \omega $ in a way that's linear, so that $ \int _ M \omega = \sum _ i \int _ { U _ i } \theta _ i \omega $ will be well-defined.

Thank you for the reply @Toby Bartels! I understand your first paragraph, now it makes sense. In the second paragraph am I right to understand that if I directly collect elements of $\omega = \sum f_i(x_1,...,x_n)dx_1\wedge ...\wedge dx_n$ by breaking this into separate $f_i(x_1,...,x_n)dx_1\wedge ...\wedge dx_n$ which correspond to some chart $(U,x)$, Then this might not be possible to integrate since the fact that $\omega$ is compactly supported does not imply each individual piece is?

Is this the reason we use partitions of unity here? What other issues might arise if I try to integrate each individual piece?

If $ \omega $ is compactly supported, then so is any form with an even smaller support.  So if by a ‘piece’ of $ \omega $ you mean a form like $ \omega _ i = \omega \theta _ i $, then these can be integrated, and that's how we integrate $ \omega $, by adding the integrals of the pieces.  (Even better, if $ \omega $ does not have compact support, we can still use an atlas of relatively compact charts so that each piece $ \omega _ i $ does have compact support and their integrals exist, so we can still define the integral of $ \omega $ as an infinite sum, if it converges.)

The reason for using a partition of unity is that you might not be able to write $ \omega $ as $ f ( x _ 1 , \ldots , x _ n ) , \mathrm d x _ 1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \mathrm d x _ n $ on the entire manifold, or even on the entire support of $ \omega $.  You're only guaranteed to be able to do that on a particular coordinate chart, and there may be no chart that covers everything.  There's no single chart that covers a sphere, for example, even thought that's compact, so you should be able to integrate any continuous $ 2 $-form.  But you need at least two pieces to do it.
